# Unknow column in field list. Couldn't find what went wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the error that I got ***Error:Unknown column 'David Beckham' in 'field list'***
I am stucked here for about 2 hours trying to figure what went wrong.
Anyone here mind to point out what's wrong with my code ?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'testdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

//logon
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
     die('Could not connect: '. msql_error());
}

// select the database you gonna work with
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
   die('Cant use' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['FullName'];
$value2 = $_POST['Email'];
$value3 = $_POST['Postcode'];
$value4 = $_POST['DateofBirth'];
$value5 = $_POST['Gender'];


//insert into table.
$sql = "INSERT INTO vajayjay (FullName, Email, Postcode, DateofBirth, Gender) VALUES (`$value`, `$value2`, `$value3`, `$value4`, `$value5`)";

if(mysql_query($sql)){
   echo "Thank you for signing up";
}else{
   die('Error:'. mysql_error());
}



mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backticks from the variables

The right way..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vajayjay (`FullName`, `Email`, `Postcode`, `DateofBirth`, `Gender`) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 0):

You are using backtrics for varibles.it is only for columns

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vajayjay (`FullName`, `Email`, `Postcode`, `DateofBirth`, `Gender`) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";
```

USE backtrics for Column names

```
(`FullName`, `Email`, `Postcode`, `DateofBirth`, `Gender`)
```

USE Quotes for variables for escaping purpose

```
('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')
```

Comment: What are backtrics - and varibles?

Comment: I do. But not sure of the relevance to my question.